# Angular TextArea validation inside a switch

Tags: angularjs, validation, textarea

I am having troubles validating 2 textareas inside a switch in angular... For example:

```
<html ng-app="CholoApp">
<head>
    <script src="angular.min.1.3.9.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var modulo = angular.module("CholoApp",[]);
    modulo.controller("CholoAppController",function($scope){
        $scope.index = 0;
        $scope.ver = function()
        {
            alert("Ver");
        }
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="CholoAppController">
    <div ng-switch on="index">
            <div  ng-switch-when="0">
                        <form name="formularioObservaciones" novalidate>
                                <textarea
                                    id="observaciones"
                                    ng-model="observacionesModel"

                                    ng-maxlength="10">
                                </textarea>

                        </form>
            </div>
    </div>
    <button type="button" ng-click="ver();" ng-disabled="!(formularioObservaciones.$valid)">Ver</button>
</body>
```

For example this code should have the button enabled... But it's disabled !. The thing is that, this happens inside the switch... Why is this hapenning ?. Also the model is reset when I switch to another case...

Hope there is a solution...

Comment: what do you mean with "For example this code should have the button enabled?" in what case should it be enabled? with what values? this tutorial may help you https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-form-validation

Comment: Thankx dennis... I meant this... If you leave the textarea empty, the button should be enabled... And I dont know why it's disabled... Thankx !...

Answer (score 1):

You have to use ng-show directive. That happens the way ng-switch and ng-if directives works, it generates it's content dynamically and form `formularioObservaciones` is unreachable. ng-show just changes html property.

Here is example how you could solve this with ng-show:

```
<body ng-controller="CholoAppController">
    <div  ng-show="index == 0">
                <form name="formularioObservaciones" novalidate>
                        <textarea
                            id="observaciones"
                            ng-model="observacionesModel"

                            ng-maxlength="10">
                        </textarea>
                </form>
    </div>
    <button type="button" ng-click="ver();" ng-disabled="!(formularioObservaciones.$valid)">Ver</button>
</body>
```

If you still want to user ng-switch you can do this like that:

```
<body ng-controller="CholoAppController">
    <div ng-switch on="index">
        <div ng-show="index == 0">
                    <form name="formularioObservaciones" novalidate>
                            <textarea
                                id="observaciones"
                                ng-model="observacionesModel"

                                ng-maxlength="10">
                            </textarea>
                    </form>
                    <button type="button" ng-click="ver();" ng-disabled="!(formularioObservaciones.$valid)">Ver</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: OOOOOHHHH thank you sooo much Domas Mar !... You rule !... Thankx